# Square payment with mean stack

Tags: node.js, angular, square

Looking for guidance on how to use Square payment form with angular and node. The form works, but when I hit send, it obviously cant get the post /process-payment. I am just not really sure where to begin, I am new to using MEAN stack. There just can not seem to find anything on how to use angular and node together to create the payment form with square. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the payment.component.ts

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

 declare var SqPaymentForm: any;

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-payment',
   templateUrl: './payment.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./payment.component.css']
 })
 export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {

  paymentForm: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  const applicationId = 'sandbox-sq0idp-HgQsUszzlyjKUGnaq6Ps0Q';

   // onGetCardNonce is triggered when the "Pay $1.00" button is clicked
   function onGetCardNonce(event) {
   // Don't submit the form until SqPaymentForm returns with a nonce
   event.preventDefault();
   // Request a nonce from the SqPaymentForm object
   paymentForm.requestCardNonce();
  }

  // Create and initialize a payment form object
  const paymentForm = new SqPaymentForm({
    // Initialize the payment form elements
    applicationId,
    inputClass: 'sq-input',

    // Customize the CSS for SqPaymentForm iframe elements
    inputStyles: [{
    fontSize: '16px',
    lineHeight: '24px',
    padding: '16px',
    placeholderColor: '#a0a0a0',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
   }],

   // Initialize the credit card placeholders
   cardNumber: {
    elementId: 'sq-card-number',
    placeholder: 'Card Number'
  },
  cvv: {
   elementId: 'sq-cvv',
   placeholder: 'CVV'
  },
  expirationDate: {
   elementId: 'sq-expiration-date',
   placeholder: 'MM/YY'
  },
  postalCode: {
   elementId: 'sq-postal-code',
   placeholder: 'Postal'
  },

 // SqPaymentForm callback functions
 callbacks: {
   /*
   * callback function: cardNonceResponseReceived
   * Triggered when: SqPaymentForm completes a card nonce request
   */
   cardNonceResponseReceived (errors, nonce, cardData) {
   if (errors) {
    // Log errors from nonce generation to the browser developer console.
    console.error('Encountered errors:');
    // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
    errors.forEach(function(error) {
        console.error('  ' + error.message);
    });
    alert('Encountered errors, check browser developer console for more 
 details');
    return;
  }

  alert(`The generated nonce is:\n${nonce}`);
// Uncomment the following block to
// 1. assign the nonce to a form field and
// 2. post the form to the payment processing handler

  ( document.getElementById('card-nonce') as HTMLInputElement).value = 
  nonce
  ( document.getElementById('nonce-form') as HTMLFormElement).submit();

  alert(`The generated nonce is:\n${nonce}`);
}
}
});

 paymentForm.build();

  }
}
```

Here is the index.js file.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const squareConnect = require('square-connect');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const accessToken = 'sandbox-sq0idp-HgQsUszzlyjKUGnaq6Ps0Q';
const locationId = 
'EAAAEHpwfQI0yn3DVT49F8TpMTI9SAVm2A3mgL_yQJTcoXXgsvXsHKfONKsXCzjj';

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

// Set square connect credentials
const defaultClient = squareConnect.ApiClient.instance;

// Configure OAuth2 access for auth: oauth2
const oauth2 = defaultClient.authentications['oauth2'];
oauth2.accessToken = accessToken;

app.post('/process-payment', function(req, res){
  const request_params = req.body;

  const idempotency_key = 
  require('crypto').randomBytes(64).toString('hex');

  // Charge the customer's card
  const transactions_api = new squareConnect.TransactionsApi();
  const request_body = {
    card_nonce: request_params.nonce,
    amount_money: {
       amount: 100, // $1.00 charge
       currency: 'USD'
     },
     idempotency_key: idempotency_key
  };
  transactions_api.charge(locationId, request_body).then(function(data) {
     const json= JSON.stringify(data);
     res.status(200).json({
      'title': 'Payment Successful',
      'result': json
    });
  }, function(error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      'title': 'Payment Failure',
      'result': error.response.text
    });
  });
});

app.listen(
  port,
  () => console.log(`listening on - http://localhost:${port}`)
);
```

Here is part of the payment.html

```
    <form id="nonce-form" novalidate action="process-payment" 
method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <div id="sq-card-number"></div>
         <div class="third">
          <div id="sq-expiration-date"><input type="text"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="third">
          <div id="sq-cvv"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="third">
          <div id="sq-postal-code"></div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <button id="sq-creditcard" class="button-credit-card" 
    onclick="onGetCardNonce(event)">Pay $1.00</button>
      <!--
        After a nonce is generated it will be assigned to this hidden 
input field.
      -->
      <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In development you angular app is most likely running on localhost:4200.

Where is you node server running on? localhost:8080? Right now your form is posting to localhost:4200/process-payment.. which obviously doesn't exist.

Create a submit function in payment.component.ts:

```
public submitMyForm(form: NgForm): void {

if(!form.valid){ // -> check if form is valid!
  return;
}

 onGetCardNonce(event) // capture callback or promise then execute your post

 $http.post('http://localhost:8080/process-payment', formData).subscribe(
   (data) => {
   console.log("success posting form to backend")
    }, // success path
   error => {
     console.log("error posting form to backend");
   }
  );
}
```

Where formData is an object wrapping all your form fields values.

You will need to modify your form to bind input values to NgModel.

```
    <form id="myForm" novalidate #myForm (ngSubmit)="submitMyForm(myForm)">
      <fieldset>
        <div id="sq-card-number"></div>
         <div class="third">
          <div id="sq-expiration-date"><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="formData.sqExpirationDate"></div>
        ...
      <button type="submit" id="sq-creditcard" class="button-credit-card">Pay $1.00</button>

      <input type="hidden" id="card-nonce" name="nonce">
    </form>
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use those square snippets straight out of the box you can, of course, change your form's action attribute to point to your backend EP.

```
<form id="myForm" novalidate #myForm action="http://localhost:8080/process-payment"
```

**Assuming your node server is on that given protocol, host and port

Comment: My component I had actually wasn't doing anything. I have a javascript file with pretty much the same code as the component I got from squares site. Is there a way from that JavaScript file to connect to node server and use the post method. I think all the post needs is just the 'nonce' ... So if I can get the value of the <input type="hidden" name="nonce> in my angular component, I could use a service in angular to connect to node... or if there is a way to just get it there from the use of the JavaScript file under assets?

Comment: @chad Please check the edit section to answer above, let me know if that works for you and if that's what you were looking for feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: I am now getting this error: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;**script-src 'self' http://onlineerp.solution.quebec 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';** ">

Comment: Still saying cannot /GET process-payment.. I will keep looking over the code and searching around. I am sure I am just missing something simple. I have just been overwhelmed with finishing my last semester of school and my mind is all over the place.. Thank you so far the help